# Calculating Confidence intervals of marginal means for a linear mixed model using emmeans package

Tags: regression, mixed-model, confidence-interval, lsmeans, ggplot2

I have built this model in R:

```
library(emmeans)
library(lmerTest)
mixed_age_interaction = lmer(basdai ~ 1 + gender + time + age +
                               gender*time + time*age + gender*age + 
                               gender*time*age + (1|ID) + (1|country), data = dat, REML = F, control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

In this model, I am predicting the treatment response **basdai** (scale 0 to 100), using **gender** (male/female), **time** (0, 0.5, 1 and 2 years, time as a categorical variable), **age** (18-90 years), and the two-way and three-way interactions of these variables. The linear mixed model takes into account correlations within subjects and subjects within countries.

I used the following code to plot the relationship between sex, time and age:

```
emmip(basdai_age,~ gender ~ time | age, at = list(age = c(20, 40, 60, 80)), plotit= TRUE)
```

This gives me the following plot **(blue = female, red = male)**:
[image]

The plot looks good, although it may be confusing for viewers to see that time is not plotted at the 1.5 year mark since it is not a measured category. Moreover, it would be helpful to add labels at the top of each subplot indicating the age group being displayed (e.g. "20 years", "40 years", etc.) to make it more clear.

Therefore I have tried to substract the data from the `emmip() function` by using `plotit = FALSE`, and subsequently trying to create the plot to my liking. However, I am struggling to calculate the confidence intervals of the estimated marginal means. I asked `chatGPT` for help which has provided me with the formula, but the CI's seem to small.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
df_basdai_age <- emmip(basdai_age,~ gender ~ time | age, at = list(age = c(20, 40, 60, 80)), facetlab = "label_both", plotit= FALSE)
df_basdai_age <- emmip(basdai_age,~ gender ~ time | age, at = list(age = c(20, 40, 60, 80)), facetlab = "label_both", plotit= FALSE)
df_basdai_age$age = as.factor(df_basdai_age$age)
levels(df_basdai_age$age) <- c("20 years", "40 years", "60 years", "80 years")
df_basdai_age$time = as.numeric(as.character(df_basdai_age$time))
df_basdai_age <- mutate(df_basdai_age, ymin = yvar - qt(0.975, df)*(SE/sqrt(df)))
df_basdai_age <- mutate(df_basdai_age, ymax = yvar + qt(0.975, df)*(SE/sqrt(df)))

#Plot the graph
p <- 
  ggplot(df_basdai_age, aes(x = time, y = yvar, color = tvar)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax), width=.05) +
  labs(x = "Time (years)", y = "") +
  theme_cowplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~ age, nrow = 2) +  theme(legend.position="none")

# show plot
p
```

This is the resulting plot:
[image]

Here is the complete dataset:

```
structure(list(gender = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Male", "Female"
), class = "factor"), time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2), age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("20 years", "40 years", 
"60 years", "80 years"), class = "factor"), yvar = c(53.2222132545591, 
55.644671238144, 53.979760945038, 58.0003674613788, 54.737308635517, 
60.3560636846136, 55.4948563259959, 62.7117599078483, 18.8785653284777, 
27.3140001897482, 25.9035670388476, 33.6311637386693, 32.9285687492176, 
39.9483272875904, 39.9535704595875, 46.2654908365116, 17.1280381612022, 
25.6617577361121, 23.8414745169542, 31.7675512043731, 30.5549108727061, 
37.8733446726342, 37.268347228458, 43.9791381408953, 15.8476044974251, 
25.0206920526655, 23.029545900933, 30.9838114430519, 30.2114873044409, 
36.9469308334382, 37.3934287079488, 42.9100502238246), SE = c(1.48085388286971, 
1.54315837900391, 1.41163641601991, 1.42678010979953, 1.4630053643472, 
1.49892114510165, 1.62355480278176, 1.73623936576435, 1.47800196744245, 
1.54052855366631, 1.41101870318731, 1.42580231659991, 1.46095633844491, 
1.4978877623696, 1.61701847301061, 1.73363627458762, 1.48984952535246, 
1.58248569215204, 1.41398647326204, 1.43575219607306, 1.47296775812952, 
1.52128548685686, 1.65241653887761, 1.80638768204503, 1.51339032203046, 
1.65536350490358, 1.41906539783371, 1.45202624858626, 1.4940999289118, 
1.56932417176622, 1.71642484529658, 1.95023658100379), df = c(19.1992529938252, 
22.636661796014, 15.8557024206515, 16.5459552649169, 18.2937320570655, 
20.157114181664, 27.7433329713143, 36.2839788594381, 19.051888835057, 
22.483155277679, 15.828184146664, 16.5012376120077, 18.1918644929504, 
20.10278950016, 27.3001430927299, 36.0701453085591, 19.669221418473, 
25.0336574427524, 15.9616355502659, 16.9666087914172, 18.7980095965655, 
21.3885230873732, 29.7715565509346, 42.514368203954, 20.9429853491516, 
29.973619949575, 16.1930278685159, 17.7496566912749, 19.9012388133609, 
24.2214091721269, 34.6602465546453, 57.7544903350949), tvar = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Male", 
"Female"), class = "factor"), xvar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("0", 
"0.5", "1", "2"), class = "factor"), ymin = c(52.5153436652014, 
54.9731205471491, 53.2276742716765, 57.258776742029, 54.0195058924355, 
59.6599914019999, 54.8631940181502, 62.1273437446853, 18.1699669372756, 
26.6410506766869, 25.1510488995009, 32.8889200571732, 32.2094835380351, 
39.2516759650496, 39.3188965541991, 45.6801042113467, 16.4265441774652, 
25.0104024242387, 23.0910485329519, 31.0320361368517, 29.8433247363632, 
37.1900266089296, 36.649658499789, 43.4202483189333, 15.1597661980371, 
24.4031685566235, 22.2826943822545, 30.2589939247067, 29.5126365026472, 
36.2891347676435, 36.8013488320248, 42.3963183501654), ymax = c(53.9290828439169, 
56.316221929139, 54.7318476183996, 58.7419581807286, 55.4551113785984, 
61.0521359672273, 56.1265186338416, 63.2961760710114, 19.5871637196797, 
27.9869497028096, 26.6560851781943, 34.3734074201655, 33.6476539604, 
40.6449786101312, 40.5882443649759, 46.8508774616764, 17.8295321449393, 
26.3131130479854, 24.5919005009564, 32.5030662718946, 31.2664970090489, 
38.5566627363388, 37.8870359571269, 44.5380279628573, 16.5354427968132, 
25.6382155487075, 23.7763974196115, 31.7086289613971, 30.9103381062346, 
37.6047268992329, 37.9855085838727, 43.4237820974838)), estName = "yvar", pri.vars = c("gender", 
"time", "age"), adjust = "none", side = 0, delta = 0, type = "link", mesg = "Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite", row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 9L, 10L, 17L, 18L, 25L, 26L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 19L, 20L, 
27L, 28L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 21L, 22L, 29L, 30L, 7L, 8L, 15L, 
16L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 32L), labs = list(xlab = "Levels of time", 
    ylab = "Linear prediction", tlab = "gender"), vars = list(
    byvars = "age", tvars = "gender"), class = "data.frame")
```

**Question**: If I have the standard error, marginal mean, degrees of freedom, how do I calculate the `ymin` and `ymax` for a marginal mean of a linear mixed model? Is the formula used here correct?

Comment: Just use `emmeans` instead of `emmip`: `emmeans(mixed_age_interaction, ~gender*time*age)`. This will give you all combinations together with the confidence intervals. Use this to make the plot to your liking. If you insist calculating it manually, the formula would be: `yvar + qt(0.975, df)*SE` (for the upper limit), I think.

Comment: @COOLSerdash thanks, I prefer to do it manually because then I don't need to transform the data from this format `emmean(mixed_age_interaction, ~gender*time*age)` to a format I can use for data visualization. Your formula seems to correspond with the CI's calculated with `emmean(mixed_age_interaction, ~gender*time*age)`. If you want, you can reply this as an answer and I can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the correct standard errors and confidence intervals by doing

```
emmeans(basdai_age, ~ gender * time | age, 
    at = list(age = c(20, 40, 60, 80)))
```

Your attempts to re-engineer the standard errors is incorrect. They are correct as they stand. You are trying to interpret standard *error* as if it is a standard *deviation* in a simple univariate situation, where standard errors are computed as $s/\sqrt{n}$. But this is not a simple univariate model and that is the wrong formula. `emmeans()` already knows the right one, so leave it alone.